# SQL Server AFTER UPDATE trigger not working when updating value from NULL

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, null

For reasons too silly to explain I have three columns in a table which hold date and time values. One column only holds the date, the second only holds the time, and the third holds a `DATETIME` value. Looks like this:

```
OPPORTUNITYID | ... | ProductionDate | ProductionTime | PRODUCTIONDATETIME
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
091798-324971 | ... | 12-07-2014     | 11:30 AM       | 2014-07-12 11:30:00:000
```

Then I have a trigger that keeps these values in sync regardless of which is being updated.
This is (part of) the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TBL_OPPORTUNITY_DUEDATES_TRU]
ON  [dbo].[TBL_OPPORTUNITY]
AFTER UPDATE
AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE ( PRODUCTIONDATETIME )
    BEGIN

        UPDATE TBL_OPPORTUNITY
        SET ProductionDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), PRODUCTIONDATETIME, 105)
        , ProductionTime = REPLACE(REPLACE(RIGHT('0'+LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, PRODUCTIONDATETIME,100), 7)), 7), 'AM', ' AM'), 'PM', ' PM')
        WHERE OPPORTUNITYID IN ( SELECT i.OPPORTUNITYID FROM inserted i
            INNER JOIN deleted d ON i.OPPORTUNITYID = d.OPPORTUNITYID
            WHERE NOT i.PRODUCTIONDATETIME = d.PRODUCTIONDATETIME
            AND NOT ( i.PRODUCTIONDATETIME = '' OR i.PRODUCTIONDATETIME IS NULL )
        );
    END

    IF ( UPDATE ( ProductionDate ) OR UPDATE ( ProductionTime ) )
    BEGIN

        UPDATE TBL_OPPORTUNITY
        SET PRODUCTIONDATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, ProductionDate + ' ' + ProductionTime, 105)
        WHERE OPPORTUNITYID IN ( SELECT i.OPPORTUNITYID FROM inserted i
            INNER JOIN deleted d ON i.OPPORTUNITYID = d.OPPORTUNITYID
            WHERE ( NOT i.ProductionDate = d.ProductionDate
                OR NOT i.ProductionTime = d.ProductionTime )
            AND NOT ( i.ProductionDate = '' OR i.ProductionDate IS NULL )
            AND NOT ( i.ProductionTime = '' OR i.ProductionTime IS NULL )
        );

        UPDATE TBL_OPPORTUNITY
        SET PRODUCTIONDATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, ProductionDate + ' 12:00:00', 105)
        WHERE OPPORTUNITYID IN ( SELECT i.OPPORTUNITYID FROM inserted i
            INNER JOIN deleted d ON i.OPPORTUNITYID = d.OPPORTUNITYID
            WHERE ( NOT i.ProductionDate = d.ProductionDate
                OR NOT i.ProductionTime = d.ProductionTime )
            AND NOT ( i.ProductionDate = '' OR i.ProductionDate IS NULL )
            AND ( i.ProductionTime = '' OR i.ProductionTime IS NULL )
        );

    END

END
GO
```

The trigger works as expected whenever any of the values are updated. However, the trigger fails (as in doesn't make any changes) if a value is being updated from `NULL`, or in other words, the old value in a column was `NULL` and the new value is, for example '02-03-2014'.

Why is that?

The server is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thank you for any clues.

Comment: What do you intend to do if an update changes all 3 columns to inconsistent values? Which value(s) are "correct"?

Comment: This never happens because the values are being changed from different sources - one source only changes the "component" values, and the other source only changes the "composite" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is written, the trigger has to ignore rows where the old values are NULL because an equality or inequality involving NULL can never evaluate to true.  A WHERE condition such as `NOT i.ProductionDate = d.ProductionDate` is never going to return any rows if d.ProductionDate is NULL, no matter what i.ProductionDate is.  You would need to explicitly check the possibility that `d.ProductionDate IS NULL` to handle the cases where d.ProductionDate has no value.

Comment: So you're saying that `NOT something = NULL` always evaluates to false?

Comment: What about `NOT (something = NULL)`?

Comment: @igor-sinkovec `NOT something = NULL` and `NOT (something = NULL)` are both equivalent to an inequality between something and NULL.  It will never evaluate to true.  Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795(v=sql.105).  The important part is:  `Comparison operators return UNKNOWN when either or both arguments are NULL.`

Answer (score 0):

Do this for every column you are tracking

```
    DECLARE @ProductionDate Date;     
    DECLARE @ProductionDateOld Date;
    DECLARE @ProductionDateInd bit = 0;  // you can use the indicator later to determine which field changed. if = 0 it didn't change, if 1 it did change
    DECLARE @ProductionDateTime DateTime;     
    DECLARE @ProductionDateTimeOld DateTime;
    DECLARE @ProductionDateTimeInd bit = 0;

    SELECT @ProductionDate=ProductionDate FROM inserted i;
    SELECT @ProductionDateOld = d.ProductionDate FROM deleted d;
    if @ProductionDateOld <> @ProductionDate 
        @ProductionDateInd = 1;
    if @ProductionDateOld IS NULL AND @ProductionDate IS NOT NULL 
        @ProductionDateInd = 1; 

SELECT @ProductionDateTime=ProductionDateTime FROM inserted i;
SELECT @ProductionDateTimeOld = d.ProductionDateTime FROM deleted d;
if @ProductionDateTimeOld <> @ProductionDateTime 
  @ProductionDateTimeInd = 1;
if @ProductionDateTimeOld IS NULL AND @ProductionDateTime IS NOT NULL 
   @ProductionDateTimeInd = 1;
```

Then check if a value changed (I do this to only write to history/audit table if there truly is a change)

```
if (@ProductionDateInd = 1 OR
@ProductionDateInd = 1)

INSERT INTO TBL_OPPORTUNITY_DUEDATES_TRU (
ProductionDate,
ProductionDateInd,
ProductionDateTime,
ProductionDateTimeInd,
.
.
.
)

VALUES (
@ProductionDate,
@ProductionDateInd,
@ProductionDateTime,
@ProductionDateTimeInd,
.
.
.
)
```