# Update trigger - both INSERTED and DELETE hold same value after update

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a table called AssociateMembers.AssociateMembershipApplication containing a column called FoundSSO, which is a unique identifier for a person (but not the primary key).

In brief the concept is that a person applying for membership of an organisation will cause a new row in this table. As part of their application, staff will check if they've been a member before, and if so, add their previous SSO into this column. Then, the Update trigger will search for the PersonID relating to that found SSO, and add it to the record.

As I'm having trouble getting the trigger to do what I want, I've simplified it to troubleshoot, and now have this code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AssociateMembers.trgApplicationSSOUpdated 
   ON  AssociateMembers.AssociateMembershipApplication 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @DeletedSSO VARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @InsertedSSO VARCHAR(20)

    IF UPDATE(FoundSSO)     
        BEGIN
            SELECT @DeletedSSO=d.FoundSSO, @InsertedSSO=i.FoundSSO
            FROM INSERTED i 
            INNER JOIN DELETED d ON i.AssociateMemberApplicationID = d.AssociateMemberApplicationID
            WHERE i.FoundSSO IS NOT NULL
            AND i.FoundSSO<>d.FoundSSO

            PRINT 'InsertedSSO:'
            PRINT ISNULL(@InsertedSSO,'NULL')

            PRINT 'DeletedSSO:'
            PRINT ISNULL(@DeletedSSO,'NULL')

        END

END
GO
```

When I issue this update command:

```
UPDATE AssociateMembers.AssociateMembershipApplication
SET FOUNDSSO='ball1138'
WHERE AssociateMemberApplicationID=64
```

The row is being updated with the new SSO, but both the variables hold NULL.

[image: Results of Update statement indicate that both INSERTED and DELETED tables hold null value]

My first thought was that there wasn't an update happening, but I've double-checked that there is indeed a change. However, this did reveal that the trigger works when there was already a value in FoundSSO and it's changed, but not when the existing FoundSSO was NULL and we're updating it to hold a value for the first time - which will be the situation most of the time.

What am I missing about the logic of my trigger? And how should I update it to work when the user updates the row from a NULL in this column to a value?

Comment: Please check if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672686/sql-server-after-update-trigger-not-working-when-updating-value-from-null solves the issue. Comparison with NULL will never evaluate to true. It might have to be explicitly handled.

Comment: If there are 0 rows being updated then the variables don't get set. Your trigger has a fatal flaw: it assumes it is executed exatcly once per row. It is actually executed per *statement* and may be on zero *or* multiple rows

Comment: See also [The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/). Anyway, what is your trigger *actually* supposed to be doing? `PRINT` is for debugging purposes, what is the trigger supposed to achieve?

Comment: Thanks Sharath.N S --> This is exactly what I'd missed. 
@Charlieface - I wasn't expecting the variables to be populated if no rows were updated, but I'd checked first that a row was being updated.  In fact, the UI means that only one row at a time can ever be updated. But, on the basis that users find ways I'd never think of to do things and, well, stuff happens, I've tried to write the live code to ensure that it would work even if multiple rows were updated. I'll add the actual (now working) trigger in my own solution above.

Comment: You could have 0 rows updated if no row exists `WHERE AssociateMemberApplicationID=64` and in case you were wondering, the `UPDATE` function does not do what you think it does. It only checks if the column was present in the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that we can see what you actually want to achieve from your answer:

You have a number of fatal flaws in your trigger:

- To compare nulls, either use `OR a IS NULL AND b IS NOT NULL` etc, or use the new `IS DISTINCT FROM`. Do not use `ISNULL` as that means that `''` and `NULL` compare as the same.
- Triggers can run on zero or multiple rows, do not assume the trigger is running on exactly one row.
- The `UPDATE` function only tells you if the column was present in the `UPDATE` statement, not if any rows were affected or if the column value ended being set to the same thing.
- You have a hidden cross-join in the `UPDATE` statement in your new answer. You need to always use the table alias on the first line to make the update, otherwise it just cross-joins the whole table again.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER AssociateMembers.trgApplicationSSOUpdated 
   ON  AssociateMembers.AssociateMembershipApplication 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT UPDATE(FoundSSO) OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
    RETURN;    -- early bailout

UPDATE ama  -- use alias
SET FoundPersonID = CASE WHEN i.FoundSSO IS NOT NULL THEN P.PersonID END
FROM AssociateMembers.AssociateMembershipApplication ama 
INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON ama.AssociateMemberApplicationID = i.AssociateMemberApplicationID
INNER JOIN DELETED d ON i.AssociateMemberApplicationID = d.AssociateMemberApplicationID
INNER JOIN People.People p ON i.FoundSSO = p.SSO
WHERE i.FoundSSO IS DISTINCT FROM d.FoundSSO;
```

Exactly why you need a trigger anyway is not clear: your application should just do the right thing in the first place.

Note also that because you are using `INNER JOIN`, if the `FoundSSO` is not matched then you may get no changes. You may want to do instead:

```sql
LEFT JOIN People.People p ON i.FoundSSO = p.SSO
```

Comment: Thanks @charlieface. 
Responding to your bullet points:
1. Cool - I didn't know about IS DISTINCT FROM
2. and 3. I thought the way I'd written this didn't make that assumption - thus testing whether INSERTED is different from DELETED.
4. Interesting. I was taught many moons ago to use the full table name in the UPDATE statement, by someone who knows masses more than me.... Will make a note for future.

Re using a trigger... can I ask why not? The application is in MS Access, and I try to keep the logic on the server as easier to update. What's the benefit of not using a trigger?

Comment: True your answer did sort out #2, and #3 was more from what you said in other comments. Triggers are inefficient for a number of reasons, in this case not least because you need to update the same row twice. It's better to just find a way to make the correct update in the first place. You could possibly write a stored procedure that does it correctly, and have MS Access call that instead.